# How to factorise $ z^5 - 32 $ into linear and quadratic factors

Tags: complex-numbers

I am a beginner to complex numbers, In problems related to $ n^{th} $ roots of unity, I was required to factorize $ z^5 - 32 $ into linear and quadratic factors  **with real coefficients**  .
Its obvious that $ ( z-2) $ is one of the factors, but what about quadratic factors? How do I find them?

Comment: use that $$32=2^5$$

Comment: A direct, if somewhat mechanical, approach is to first divide by $x-2$ and then factor the quartic as $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and solve for the $4$ coefficients.

Comment: A less mechanical approach is to note that the complex roots are all of the form $2\zeta_5^i$ where $\zeta_5$ denotes a primitive fifth root of unity.  Since you want real coefficients you'll want to combine conjugate terms.

Comment: @lulu I'm getting $ z^4 + 2z^3 + 4z^2+8z+16 $ how to convert it into $ (x^2 + ax+b)(x^2+cx+d) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hands on method.

First set $2y=z$ so that the polynomial becomes $32(y^5-1)$ - this simplifies the arithmetic.

Now notice the easy linear factor $y-1$ so that you have the factorisation $$(y-1)(y^4+y^3+y^2+y+1)$$

Now notice that the second factor $g(y)$ has coefficients $1,1,1,1,1$ which read the same backwards and forwards. This is an indication to try the substitution $x=y+\frac 1y$ with $x^2=y^2+\frac 1{y^2}+2$. Define

$$h(x)=\frac {g(y)}{y^2}=y^2+y+1+\frac 1y+\frac 1{y^2}=x^2+x-1$$

Then $h(x)$ factors as $\left(x-\frac {-1+\sqrt5}2\right)\left(x-\frac {-1-\sqrt5}2\right)$ and you can work backwards to the factorisation you need.

---

So $x=y+\frac 1y= \frac z2 +\frac 2z$ and you have a factor $32=2\times 4\times 4$ to put back in.

You get $$(z-2)\left(z^2-(-1+\sqrt5)z+4\right)\left(z^2-(-1-\sqrt5)z+4\right)$$

Comment: How to get the factors in the form $ (x^2 + ax+b)(x^2+cx+d) $

Comment: @MaanavRoy Have done that.

Comment: My request is that to add another method when coefficients are not $ 1,1,1,1,1 $

Comment: @MaanavRoy If the coefficients read the same forward as backward, you have that solutions come in pairs: if $y$ is a solution, so is $\frac 1y$. This is true in particular of cyclotomic polynomials. This method halves the degree of the polynomial you have to factorise. That sometimes helps a lot if you can't see what else to do. The methods using complex numbers work better for general cyclotomic polynomials, because they give explicit factorisations whatever the degree. But the easy route gives trigonometric functions without indicating whether they can be expressed in terms of square roots.

Comment: Okay, but on factoring, I was getting $ (z-2)( z^4 + 2z^3 + 4z^2+8z+16 ) $ how to proceed this further?

Comment: If you put $2y=z$ you get $(2y-2)(16y^4+16y^3+16y^2+16y+16)$.

Comment: Okay, then proceed in your way?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the roots of $z^5-1$. If $\alpha$ solves $\alpha^5 = 1$, clearly $(\alpha\cdot 2)^5 = 32$, so you just have to find the roots of $z^5-1$, which is easy.

Comment: this is the same answer as mine

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no it isn't.

Comment: ok it is not the same you have right

Comment: For the quadratic factors, just think of what happens if you multiply linear factors like $(z-a)\cdot(z-b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are complex conjugates.

Comment: I'm getting $ z^4 + 2z^3 + 4z^2+8z+16 $ how to convert it into $ (x^2 + ax+b)(x^2+cx+d) $

Answer (score 1):

Roots of $32$ are
$$
z_0=2, z_1=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)\right),
z_2=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)\right),
z_3=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}{5}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{6\pi}{5}\right)\right),
z_4=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)\right).
$$
Those roots that are conjugate of each other correspond to quadratic factors. $z_1$ and $z_4$ are conjugate and $z_2$ and $z_3$ are conjugate. To get one quadratic factor expand $(z-z_1)(z-z_4)$, to get the other expand $(z-z_2)(z-z_3)$.